# Assigning layers to images in 2D JavaFX racing game

Tags: java, javafx

Me and a few friends are making a simple 2D racing game in JavaFX without using a game specific framework.

We would like to assign images to different layers, i.e. to make the racing car pass over/under bridges. Is this possible in JavaFX or is there any other way of doing this?

We're using `ImageView` at the moment to display all the graphics.

Constructor for the Actor class:

```
public Actor(String name, String filename, int sizeX, int sizeY){
this.name = name;
imageView = new ImageView();
imageView.setImage(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/"+filename)));
imageView.setFitWidth(sizeX);
imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);      
setSize(sizeX, sizeY);
```

The primary stage is declared like this:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
gui = this;

root = new Pane();

Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");
root.setId("pane_background");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at the [StackPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html):

> StackPane lays out its children in a back-to-front stack. The z-order of the children is defined by the order of the children list with the 0th child being the bottom and last child on top. [...]